# How do I reconnect my web pages on my website after updating to PHP 7 with a MySQL database 5.0.0?<?

Tags: php, mysql

I added the i updates to communicate with the database & now the page links don't work.

```
<?php
// Connect to database
$link=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');
mysqli_select_db($link, 'waddellc_PHRDB');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM quotes ORDER BY id";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysql_error());

$tenant_quotes = array();
$owner_quotes = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what? Do you get errors? Are you checking for those? MySQL 5.0.0 should be in a museum, it's from 2003, so don't use it. The latest 5.7 version is probably 100% backwards compatible with your needs.

Comment: No Errors & since I tried to place the new i's in the PHP code to communicate almost every webpage that was connecting only shows a eroor below that it goes to after clicking on my links which should e re directed to a correct webpage. 
404 Error File Not Found

The page you are looking for might have been removed, 
had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Then your virtual host isn't configured correctly. Work on that part first. Maybe check out [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) for more specific advice there.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work, using PDO :

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password123";
$conn = null;
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=databaseName", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
if(!is_null($conn)){
       $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM quotes ORDER BY id");
       if ($stmt->execute()) {
           while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                print_r($row);
           }
       }
}
```

I also think you need to update your database, it's quite old now.

Comment: It's what I did, just change the username/password/databaseName and replace the print_r($row) by what you need.

Comment: I'm Confused on what to use!

Mine didn't have the new PDO & CONN code & would it  be to much to ask if you could possible show an example of your new idea PLEASE?

Comment: What do I change & what do I leave in my Original Code is the confusing part along with this new PDO & CONN coding?

Comment: I don't understand the problem, I replace ALL your code, so just use mine, it makes the connection to the database and then does your SELECT.
I don't repeat `$tenant_quotes = array();
$owner_quotes = array();` because I don't know what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks Guys!   I'll try it & update you on the results later if that's feasible with you?